# DataTable Find Item

Tags: c#, datatable

im trying to do something like this

```
 var names_en = dtTmp.AsEnumerable();
 var names = names_en.Where(a => a["ID"] == "1");
 string name = names["Name"].ToString();
```

My goal is to find the row where `ID` equalls `1` and keep the `Name` as string

I know I have `ID` collumn I know that I have a row where `ID==1` I see it in the debugger.
but `names` lets that enumeration yields no results.

also is there a better way to do this?

Comment: try: `var names = names_en.Where(a => a["ID"].equals("1"));`

Comment: @ronen - I think its good to consider ID as numeric rather than string...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its better if you use [`DataRowExtension.Field`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891.aspx) method which is strongly typed. Also make sure you `ID` is of type string, otherwise you will get an exception. You may specify the type accordingly.

```
string name = dtTmp.AsEnumerable()
                .FirstOrDefault(r => r.Field<string>("ID") == "1")
                .Field<string>("Name");
```

Comment: @NahumLitvin, I can only guess, but I believe you can't compile your existing code. `names["Name"]` is not allowed on a collection. You may try `names_en.Where(a => a["ID"] == "1").First();` on the earlier line and then it should work, or the other reason could be that Your ID is of type `int` and your comparison in the current form will not return any result, since you are comparing it against a string

Answer (score 0):

```
var names = names_en.Where(a => a["ID"] == "1");
```

return the List of result you must get the first record